# how to change position of a div from fixed to sticky within a container div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my example code, below. I have an overlay div with fixed position, such that it appears at the bottom of the viewport( not the browser window). but when scrolled this div overlaps the footer. I would like this to remain with the bounds of the content div, almost like a sticky top header when scrolled it sticks to the top. is there a way to do this by just css, or with css/js?

```css
#container {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
#container::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
#container {
 position:relative;
   z-index: 1;
   overflow-x:hidden;
 }

 #content {
   z-index: 1;
   border: 2px solid blue;
   height:1100px;
 }

 #overlay {
   height: 100px;
   width: 450px;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 10px;
   z-index: 3;
   background: yellow;
   opacity: .75;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
 }

 #footer {
   background: black;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
   margin-top:30px;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
        <p>Header</p>
      </div>
      <div id="container" >
        <div id="leftMenu"></div>
        <div id="content">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                <div id="overlay">
                    <input type="button" value="Close me " id="tauko" style="background-color:green;margin:20px;height:50px;width:140px;font-weight: bold;font-size: larger;" title="Close">
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>Footer</p>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you mean that，I think it is possible to modify the position of `content` and `overlay`

```
#content {
        z-index: 1;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        position: relative;
        height: 1100px;
    }

    #overlay {
        height: 100px;
        width: 450px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        z-index: 3;
        background: yellow;
        opacity: .75;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```